# Wordpress Update User Meta SQL Timeout

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site with over 8000 users. I routinely need to run scripts that update all of the users meta based on some activity on the site.  For example I want to scan my activity logs and update a users account level based on the highest level action they took in the last 270 days.  I want to run a PHP script that does something like this:

1. $users = get_users();
2. Loop through that result and run a SQL query to get some values I need about each user
3. run update_user_meta for each user to update some values for that user

So far every time I do this the script times out.  My only work around is to create a form so I can control the number of users to perform the script on and the offset to start at.  This creates a lot of work (having to sit there and change the numbers and hit submit). I have tried all sorts of MYSQL and php config settings but nothing stops the timeout.

Is there another way to do this?  I would love to turn these into cron jobs that were done nightly.

Thank you in advance